# How to flip / produce the mirror image of a special character in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, reflection

I'm producing a menu with xelatex using the font Bickham Script Pro. It has a swirly pattern I'd like to use at the beginning and end of a line. The swirly character would need to be flipped to have the correct end pointing inwards towards the text. Is there a way to do this as I can't find one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An example for `xelatex` and `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Bickham Script Pro}
 \usepackage{graphicx}     
\begin{document}          
\reflectbox{Foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An example for `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\script[1]{{\fontfamily{pzc}\fontshape{it}\selectfont#1}}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{\script{Foo}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `fontspec` doesn't seem to work with `pdflatex`, is there an alternative?

Comment: see my edited answer. There are not a big number of script fonts for pdflatex.