# How to print character backwards?

Tags: fonts

In my desktop publishing I use EHP as my imprint. I would like, however, for the E to print facing the other direction. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to flip / produce the mirror image of a special character in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25484/5764)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by EHP, but there are at least two ways to get a rotated E.

**Use graphicx (or graphics) Package**

A character can be rotated using the 
graphicx (or graphics) package's `\reflectbox` and `\rotatebox` macros.

(Please see the comment  from [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) after this answer for the possible usages of the two.)

**Use a LaTeX math Symbol**

This may not be the solution you are looking for, mainly due to aesthetics issues, but decided to mention this anyway. You can use the math symbol `\exists` to 
get something like a rotated E, albeit thin.

---

The following code included both the abovementioned solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\rotatecharone#1{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#1}}

\def\rotatechartwo#1{\reflectbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

\rotatecharone{E}HP, \rotatechartwo{E}HP

\large\rotatecharone{E}HP, \rotatechartwo{E}HP

\Huge\rotatecharone{E}HP, \rotatechartwo{E}HP

\normalsize

\bigskip

$\exists$HP

\end{document}
```

---

The following is the output.

[image]

Comment: In case the "E" character's shape is slightly asymmetric, e.g., if the middle bar isn't precisely in the middle between the top and bottom bars, it may be better to use `\reflectbox{#1}` rather than `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#1}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot. I was trying comprehend the nuance of the two available commands and you have put forth that enlightment.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought to look at unicode but tried Masroor's fix first. I only wanted to change the direction of E one time so I didn't use a `\def`. I had found the `\kern-x` statement somewhere sometime ago. `\textrm{\normalsize \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{E}\kern-0.3em H\kern-0.4em P} \\ \textrm{Euthus House Publishing}`. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, rotating is certainly a bad idea, notice how the top bar is longer than the bottom bar in the 1st variant.

Answer (score 7):

Unicode example (tested on MacTeX, should be similar on other platforms):

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
ƎHP
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is less an answer than a comment that’s too long for the comment section.

Because a logo suggests the quality of a company’s work, it’s best, if you can afford it, to get a font with the ligatures you need, because `\reflectbox` or `\rotatebox` with kerning makes the stems of the H too thick. I happen to have one font with the ligatures you need; there are probably others (I’d try to find them by searching for the titling feature).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{EstragonPro}[
  Style=TitlingCaps]
\begin{document}
\sffamily
EHP
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the sample above]

This copies and pastes as EHP.

Answer (score 3):

"Ǝ" is available in mathmode: `$\exists$`

Comment: Great answer, simple and short. I have no idea why somebody made a negative vote.